# Timestamp query to hours

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I need some help with timestamps with postgresql. I have a column for the timestamp with timezone named `download_at` for when a user downloaded an app and a column `user_id` which is an integer. I am trying to extract user IDs of users that have downloaded within the last 168 hours from the last 60 days of information. I am a bit confused on how I can approach this and felt stuck because of the two different times. I believe I might have to play around with the trunc function but felt a bit stuck.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'from the last 60 days of information? Some sample data structures would be helpful.

Comment: Hmm it just says get information for over the last 60 days of users with the app within 168 hours of the download.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE download_at > now() - '186 hours'::interval
```

Postgres is **phenomenal** at handling dates and times. A breakdown of what this does:

```
now() --function that returns the current time as a datetime object

'186 hours'::interval --a string cast to an interval
```

In postgres `::` does casting. When casting to an interval Postgres will turn formatted English to an interval object. Since you can subtract datetime and interval objects it'll do the rest for you.